# how to create flex combobox for dropdown list

Tags: list, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, combobox

I want to create a flex combobox, but need to group display, and have three levels, the fomat as below. Anyone who has this experience?

Font dropdown List

1. Chinese:

   1.1.  Simplified Chinese:

   1.1.1.     Fang Song

   1.1.2.     Hei

   1.1.3.     Kai

   1.1.4.     Song

   1.2.  Traditional Chinese:

   1.2.1.     Kai

   1.2.2.     Sung
2. Japanese:

   2.1.  Japanese Heisei Kaku Gothic

   2.2.  Japanese Heisei Maru Gothic

   2.3.  Japanese Heisei Mincho
3. Korean:

   3.1.  Korean Gothic

   3.2. Korean Myengjo

Comment: Do you want to display the list as we see it in your question? Or do you want the root items te be collapsed at the start and expanded when clicked?

Comment: In theory; you can extend DropDownListBase and use a customized component in the drop down; such as an AdvancedDataGrid.  I'm not sure how trivial the development will be or how well it will perform; but that is probably the approach I'd take.  If you don't need expand/collapse functionality then you can probably get away with a simple itemRenderer that adds spacing based on whether the element is a 'top level category' or a subcategory.

Comment: Hi RIAstar, I want to display the list as we see it in my question, no need to collapse. just like a dropdown list, can selelct 1.1.1 Fang Song as value, but cannot select Simplified Chinese or Chinese as value.

Comment: Thanks for www.Flextras.com, I got it.

Comment: Below link may help u... http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/06/disabling_list_selection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### step 1: create a model class with some sense of hierarchical depth

In its simplemst form, something like this:

```
public class Node {

    public var label:String;
    public var depth:int;

}
```

### step 2: create a custom ItemRenderer that translates that `depth` into visual padding

```
<!-- HierarchicalItemRenderer.mxml -->
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" left="3 + (10 * data.depth)"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

### step 3: use custom ItemRenderer

```
<DropDownList itemRenderer="path.to.HierarchicalItemRenderer"/>
```

with an `IList` of `Node` instances as a dataProvider.